# libgdx android Local file

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm trying to save the Setting in a Local .txt file. But I don't know where i have to put the txt file, that the desktop as well as the android application can find it.

I hope you can help me with this little Problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For settings, I'd probably just use the LibGDX Preferences interface which works cross-platform. On Android, it uses `SharedPreferences`, on Desktop it uses an XML file stored in the user's home directory.

The Local file type in LibGDX provides access to the internal app-specific storage (`/data/data/com.company.package/files`) on Android, and stores the file alongside the jar for Desktop. There is no way to provide a Local file up front at compile time, aside from packing it as an Internal file and extracting it to a Local (or otherwise generating the file with code at run-time).

Answer (score 0):

settings are usually stored using android.content.SharedPreferences:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

or you can write the txt file to the device, see this tutorial:

http://chrisrisner.com/31-Days-of-Android--Day-23%E2%80%93Writing-and-Reading-Files